# ASP.NET MVC Core - OutputCache on Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

When trying to test this

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400, VaryByParam = "id"]
public ActionResult Index(string id) {

}
```

The result is that Index action is still executed?? I would expect the whole html page is stored in the cache memroy for 1 day in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

To your `Configure` method in `Startup` class add:

```
            app.UseResponseCaching();
```

and change the attribute as follows:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration=86400, VaryByParam = "id"]
public ActionResult Index(string id) {

}
```